# How to i do a 'fuzzy string comparison' to check spelling of word in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, spelling

I want to implement a spell checker in my iphone app and I was wondering how to do a 'fuzzy string comparison' between the entered string and the NSArray containing the dictonary words and highlight possible corrections?

Is there a class that will do this already or a library that someone can recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the edit distance computation is pretty straight-forward, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance